# not_if not working as expected in bash resource

Tags: bash, grep, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I have written a bash resource as follows:

```
bash 'initialize_vault' do
  environment (node['vault']['env'])
  code <<-EOH
    vault init > /etc/vault/keys
  EOH
 not_if { vault init | grep 'initialized' }
end
```

It seems that not_if is not working as expected as bash is executing every single time.

What is correct way to write `not_if` here?

Comment: Silly question here, but are you sure the `initialized` content you're looking for is written to stdout rather than stderr (which is where logging/status data is, by convention, *supposed* to go)?

Comment: It's also been a while since I've worked with chef, but passing a string of shell in that form rather than as, well, a *string* is surprising. `not_if 'vault init 2>&1 | grep -q initialized'` smells more like what I remember being correct.

Comment: That said, in context, the underlying logic here is unlikely to be correct. Consider what this actually does: You're *always* running `vault init` at once -- when evaluating the `not_if` clause -- and after that trying to run it a second time if that `not_if` clause didn't return true. That doesn't make sense: If you don't want to run it if it's already initialized, then how is it safe to run in the `not_if` clause?

Comment: The only scenario where that makes sense is if it reads `/etc/vault/keys` as input to determine whether it's initialized, but if `vault` knew about that file, why would you need to redirect output there yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, rewind. `not_if` has two very different modes. You can pass it a string like `not_if "foo bar"` which will run the string as a command. You can also give it a Ruby block like `not_if { foo('bar') }` which will run the block as Ruby code. You've crossed the streams here :)